# Can't seed database after using destroy_all from command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my application I have Posts that Users can create. When I initially started my project, I created some placeholder Posts and Users from the command line just so I can play around. As the application advanced I created a seed file and ran 'rake db:seed' from the command line. Everything worked fine but I realized that I still had the placeholder Posts and Users still in the database so I decided to delete them. I decided to destroy all Posts and Users from the command line using the 'destroy_all' method. I just wanted to see if it would work and it did as everything was deleted. But now when I run 'rake db:seed' to populate the database, nothing shows up. I get no errors and nothing gets returned when I run Post.all or User.all from the command line. I'm not sure what's going on but I would appreciate any assistance, thank you!

```
User.create(name: 'John', email: 'John@gmail.com', password: '123456', password_confirmation: '123456')
User.create(name: 'Bill', email: 'Bill@gmail.com', password: '123456', password_confirmation: '123456')


Post.create([
  {
    user_id: 1,
    category_id: 1,
    title: "Tech tattoos put a working circuit board on your skin",
    url: "http://www.slashgear.com/tech-tattoos-put-a-working-circuit-board-on-your-skin-25416060/" 
  },
  {
    user_id: 2,
    category_id: 1,
    title: "This robot can print emoji on your fingernails",
    url: "http://mashable.com/2015/11/24/nailbot-printed-manicure/#Rml2qXalMmqp" 
  },
  {
    user_id: 3,
    category_id: 2,
    title: "Thiago Silva scores a goal from behind the goal",
    url: "http://www.gyfbin.com/2015/11/hgfp.gif.html" 
  }])
```

Comment: Where is the content of the seed file?

Comment: I ran the seed file before using the destoy_all method and it worked fine so I'm not sure the problem is here but I could be wrong. I have 5 users total but only listed 2 here

Comment: Did you run `rake db:migrate` again?

Comment: Yes, but I still get nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a simple way to you can see error message at. You can use bang (!) after create method (ex: User.create!(.....), Post.create!(.....)). Console will raise error message when have any errors. 
If you do same that. you can search yourself error.

Comment: Thanks huyhoang.framgiavn, I came across a post that mentioned the same thing and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

`destroy_all` doesn't **drop** the table. First you ran the seed file. so, 5 users were created with ID (1 to 5). It destroys the USERS but not truncate. Then you destroy those users. Again ran the seed file. Now the 5 users were created with ID (6 to 10). So, there is no `user_id` with 1 anymore. It may be the problem.

solution 1: You can drop the tables (user, post) and then migrate and seed.

solution 2:
pick user ids randomly. Use:

```
users = User.all.collect{|u| u.id}
# same goes for category.
Post.create([
  {
    user_id: users.sample,
    category_id: 1,
    title: "Tech tattoos put a working circuit board on your skin",
    url: "http://www.slashgear.com/tech-tattoos-put-a-working-circuit-board-on-your-skin-25416060/" 
  },
  {
    user_id: users.sample,
    category_id: 1,
    title: "This robot can print emoji on your fingernails",
    url: "http://mashable.com/2015/11/24/nailbot-printed-manicure/#Rml2qXalMmqp" 
  },
  {
    user_id: users.sample,
    category_id: 2,
    title: "Thiago Silva scores a goal from behind the goal",
    url: "http://www.gyfbin.com/2015/11/hgfp.gif.html" 
  }])
```

Hope it helps!